# How to increase speed of PHP script that using MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, excel, performance

I wrote a PHP script that read some data from an excel file using [this library](https://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/source/browse/trunk/excel_reader2.php?r=5) .

Then insert it in MySQL database in my arbitrary sequence to some tables.

This Excel file has 200 rows with 50 columns and usually execution time for it takes more than 60 seconds. because of my PHP hosting doesn't allow me to use `set_time_limit(0);` in your opinion How can I increase speed of my scripts?

My scripts to read each row:

```
 function read_row($excelFile, $r){
    require_once './inc/excel_reader2.php';
    $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader($excelFile, FALSE);
    $col[0] = $data->val($r, 'E');
    $col[1] = $data->val($r, 'F');
    ...
    $col[49] = $data->val($r, 'BZ');
    return $col;
 }
```

My scripts to insert data to MySQL:

```
$count = $user->rowcount($sheet=0); 
    if($final>0){
        $count = $final;
    }
    $users = 0;
    for($i = 4; $i <= $count; $i++){
        $f = $user->val($i,'D');
        $c = $user->val($i,'B');
        $l = $user->val($i,'C');
        $query = "INSERT INTO users(fullname ,ncode, location, createdtime) VALUES('$f','$c','$l', now());";
        if(mysql_query($query)){
            $users++;
        }
        $row = read_row($excelFile, $i);
        $query = "INSERT INTO `payments` (`id`, `year`, `month`, `user`, `p1`, `p2`,... `p50`) VALUES"
                . " (NULL, '$y', '$m', '$c', '$row[0]', '$row[1]', ..., '$row[49]');";
        mysql_query($query);
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you're re-opening the spreadsheet with every row.  Is there a way to load the entire spreadsheet into an array, and then loop through that instead?

Comment: The slow player is PhpExcel, not MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things here:

Use `microtime(true)` to benchmark your script. It is useful for you to know where exactly the script takes longest.

e.g.

```
$read_file_time = microtime(true); //true makes function return value in seconds
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader($excelFile, FALSE);
$col[0] = $data->val($r, 'E');
$col[1] = $data->val($r, 'F');
...
$col[49] = $data->val($r, 'BZ');

//Output this to screen, or log it, or whatever    
$read_file_time = microtime(true) - $read_file_time; //end time - start time

return $col;
```

Do the same for your DB inserts.

Next, I would suggest using batch inserts.

Generate an array of rows and insert those all at once rather than your single row at a time method that you are using right now.

So your array would look something like

```
$rows = array(
  array('value for col-0', 'value for col-1' ... 'col-49'), //row 1
  array('value for col-0', 'value for col-1' ... 'col-49'), //row 2, etc.
);
```

And your query will look something like

```
INSERT INTO `payments` (`id`, `year`, `month`, `user`, `p1`, `p2`,... `p50`) VALUES
(NULL, '$y', '$m', '$c', '$row[0][0]', '$row[0][1]', ..., '$row[0][49]'),
(NULL, '$y', '$m', '$c', '$row[1][0]', '$row[1][1]', ..., '$row[1][49]'),
...
(NULL, '$y', '$m', '$c', '$row[101][0]', '$row[101][1]', ..., '$row[101][49]')
```

Depending on how big the file is, you may need to do this in batches as well.

Finally, you (as @mellamokb points out) you are opening the file every single loop. Instead, you should try something like:

```
function read_row($ExcelFile, $r){

    /*$col[0] = $ExcelFile->val($r, 'E');
    $col[1] = $ExcelFile->val($r, 'F');*/

    //Instead of the above, use a loop
    $col = array();        
    $num_cols = $ExcelFile->colcount();        
    for($i = 0; $i < $num_cols; $i++) {
      $col[] = $ExcelFile->val($r, $i);
    }

    //Or you can use column names if you really want
    //Pass the `$col_names` as a function parameter tho
    $col_names = array('E', 'F', 'BZ');
    $num_cols = count($col_names);
    for($i = 0; $i < $num_cols; $i++) {
      $col[] = $ExcelFile->val($r, $col_names[$i]);
    }


    return $col;
 }

 require_once './inc/excel_reader2.php';
 $DataFile = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader('path to your file', FALSE);
 for($i = 4; $i <= $count; $i++) {
   $row = read_row($DataFile, $i);
 }
```

So to incorporate my above suggestions, you could do something like:

```
//@param $ExcelFile : excel reader2 file object
//@param $start_row : Row to start reading from, 0 based
//@param $num_rows  : Number of rows to read
function read_n_rows($ExcelFile, $start_row, $num_rows) {
   $rows = array();
   for($i = $start_row; $i < $num_rows; $i++) {
      $rows[] = read_row($ExcelFile, $i)
   }

   return $rows;
}
```